# Wear OS app and associated phone app version number issue

Tags: wear-os

I have published Phone app and wear OS app both together. But I forgot to set Opt-in to Wear OS settings. Now I want to release one more wear OS build with Opt-in to Wear OS settings turned on. Is it okay to release just wearOS apk with updated version number?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should publish both apps together. It may cause your mobile app to no show up in search if you publish without it.